# Позиционирование объектов в зависимости от размеров экрана

Tags: c#, unity3d

Столкнулся с проблемой при работе с Unity.
Мне нужно, чтобы на границах экрана были стены (не важно, видимые или нет). Однако заметил, что про изменении размеров экрана эти стены уходят за кадр (сейчас они организованы в виде спрайтов):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, в какую сторону стоит копать и как реализовать, чтобы на всех экранах стены были менно по краям видимой зоны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Ваша игра выполнена в 2D, то самым простым способом будет использовать свойства [Camera.orthographicSize](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-orthographicSize.html) и [Camera.aspect](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-aspect.html) Вашей камеры. Так Вы сможете узнать размеры видимой области в мировых координатах.

Далее, нужно будет заскейлить стены и расположить их по краям видимой области.

Что то типа:

```
var camera = Camera.main;
var halfHeight = camera.ortogtaphicSize;
var halfWidth = halfHeight * camera.aspect;
var center = camera.transform.position;

leftWall.transform.position = center + Vector3.left * halfWidth;
leftWall.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, halfHeight);

...
```

Код писал от балды, так что могут быть синтаксические ошибки... Ваша среда разработки Вам об этом сообщит)

---

Возможно, при расположении стен, Вам нужно будет учесть их ширину и высоту. Для этого можно использовать свойства [Renderer.bounds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-bounds.html) и/или [Collider2D.bounds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D-bounds.html)

Comment: Практически так и решил проблему, только вместо этого использовал костыль: получаю размеры экрана (Screen.width\height), высчитываю отношение сторон и уже в зависимости от этого позиционирую элементы. Наверное Ваш способ - и есть избавление от костыля.